# Deriving Geometric Progression from 3-Sided Dice Problem

Tags: combinatorics

I have stumbled upon solving for the number of solutions to rolling 2, 3, 4 & 5 die rolls of 3-sided dice. For example, Let `i` denote 1 face of a die, each face differing to another, and taking a value such that `i={-1,0,1}`. How many combinations are possible for any number of dice? In other words, how do I generalise the solution by finding the geometric progression?

My initial attempts centered around drawing trees and, by brute force, listing each possible combination under each of the 7 "legs", such as `{-1}`, `{-1,0}`, `{0}`, `{0,1}`, `{1}`, `{-1,1}`, `{-1,0,1}` for games of 3 or more die. This method produced sequences for 4 and 3 dies respectively **S<sub>4</sub> = { 3, 9, 27, 69 }** and **S<sub>3</sub> = { 2, 4, 8, 16, 30 }**.

Now, I derived the following solution for 3 die: **E<sub>i</sub> = t<sub>i-2</sub> + t<sub>i-1</sub> + 2(i-2), when i>1**. But not making much progress with 4 die.

So, firstly, is there a simpler way to calculate these combinations? Secondly, how would a trained mathematician approach this problem?

Comment: How many $n$-digit numbers can you construct from digits $1,2,3$ (repeated digits are allowed)?

Comment: Think I understand your question, @user. In essence, given 2 die with 3 faces, each face one of `{ -1, 0, 1 }`, then the **n**-digit numbers = **9**, or `{ 0,0 }`, `{ 0,1 }`, `{ 1,0 }`, `{ 1,1 }`, `{ -1,-1 }`,  `{ -1,1 }`, `{ 1,-1 }`, `{ -1,0 }`, `{ 0,-1 }`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, and this is easy to generalize, because the choice of a digit for a certain position is independent of the choice for other positions.